# Correct way to use UseEffect?

Tags: reactjs

Is it a problem/bad habit to add codes that does conditional rendering based on states or values that update constantly outside the useEffect hook.

Like this

```
function Home() {
 const { state } = useLocation();  
 const [validation, setValidation] = useState();
 const [MainData, setMainData] = useState();

  if(true)  
     do somthing....
  else
    do somthing....
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    something else.....         
  })

  return (

   );
 }
```

Or should i do it this way??

```
function Home() {
 const { state } = useLocation();  
 const [validation, setValidation] = useState();
 const [MainData, setMainData] = useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (true)  
      do somthing....
    else
      do somthing....

    something else....
  })

  return (

  );
}
```

But if it do it the second way sometimes i get warnings about dependencies. Is that like a major problem should i just ignore it??

Comment: do inside useEffect

Comment: rendering is for output, `useEffect` is for side effects like network requests

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **both** examples definitely are bad habits.

The statements in both will be run on every re-render since you didn't add a dependency array in your second example. You should use the useEffect hook with a dependency array and add the dependencies (or leave an empty array if you only want to run the code on the first mount of the component). In my experience there barely is any case where re-calculations on every re-render are necessary and I had to find out the hard way that such calculations can really hurt the performance of your app, especially when using concurrent react.

If you want to declare an arrow function in your component or calculate a value that you want to render I advice you to use the [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) or [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook.